# Url a href in gmail still redirects to localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

Good morning.

I have written an asp.net c# web application. It has in it a code to send email message to a user who fills a form. Inside the message body is

```
<a href='http://localhost:5614/reg.aspx'>online registration</a>.
```

I changed it to suit the new server

```
<a href='http://reg.somee.com/reg.aspx/'>online registration</a>
```

But when the user receives the message, 'online registration' still redirects to localhost. Can anybody help. I need it to redirect to the new server?

Answer (score 0):

instead of typing the name completely use the Request.Uri class to get the path of the reg.aspx page

regards

Comment: please can you put an example there for me

Comment: something like this ==> Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath,string.Empty) + "/reg.aspx"; // note that when you publish your website the result will not come as localhost

Comment: string body = "<html>Thank You for applying to our University. The following are your details. <br></br>Username:'" + this.txtUser.Text + "' <br></br> Password is '" + this.txtPass.Text + "' <br></br> Please follow this link to register online   <a href='http://localhost:5614/reg.aspx'>online registration</a></html>";     // please where do I put the request.uri  code

Comment: you got this result since your are running the application on localhost, you should publish the application to the server that has different name, in other words: don't use the localhost to test the application.

Comment: Even when a user on another computer fills the form he gets an email and the 'online registration ' tries to find localhost again then it throws an error page not found

Comment: And I have uploaded the application to the new server

Comment: string body = "<html>Thank You for applying to our University. The following are your details. <br></br>Username:'" + this.txtUser.Text + "' <br></br> Password is '" + this.txtPass.Text + "' <br></br> Please follow this link to register online <a href='" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath,string.Empty) + "/reg.aspx" + "'>online  registration</a></html>";  // i modified your body , try it now please